# How to create a class with templated class variables as template arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I have started learning templates in c++, and i would like to make a class that has a variable number of variables of a templated class.
In other words, I have a class A

```
template<typename T>
class A;
```

Now I would like to make a class B such that the class would be instantiated like so:

```
B<A<int>(1), A<float>(2.4f), A<bool>(false),....>();
```

I managed to make a pretty strightforward templated function that does the same thing, like this:

```
template<typename C>
void test(A<C> args...) {}

test(A<int>(1), A<bool>(true),...) // works fine
```

Is it possible to do it with a class, and if so, how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really, i would like to have those A variables available at compile time, and also have them kind of like member variables

Comment: Basically, i would like to have a variable number of Bs, in all variations (B<int>, B<float>, B<any type>,...), and have them available at compile time for their values as well as having a number of them available (which i can't do with vectors or maps for example) at compile time as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you're searching for is likely already provided by the standard class `std::tuple<>`, albeit with a slightly different syntax:

```
auto b = std::tuple<int, float, bool>(1, 2.4f, false);
// or
auto b2 = std::make_tuple(1, 2.4f, false);
```

Then you can access the elements using `std::get<i>(b)`.